# Gradle main source code substitution

Tags: java, android, gradle, preprocessor

I'm trying to generated a pre-processed source code in Android, I'm applying some regex-es to my code through a Gradle task and copying that modified code to a new folder within the build folder, this is working properly, but the missing part is that after preprocessing the code, and setting the source for the Android task, gradle complains about duplicated classes. I want to replace the main srcDir for some specific cases (when the build is a Release build specifically) but I can't override the path for the classes to avoid the code duplication. How can I achieve this?

My gradle task as follow :

```
task filterComments(type: Copy) {
    from "$projectDir/src/main/java"
    into "$projectDir/build/generated-src"
    filter { line -> line.replaceAll('LoremIpsumDolor', 'LOREMIPSUMDOLOR') }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    task -> if (task.name.contains("compileRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn filterComments
        task.source "$projectDir/build/generated-src"
    }
}
```